# Do Quakers typically have their marriage records recorded with the government?

Tags: marriage-records, 17th-century, marriage-practices, virginia, quakers

I'm looking for a supposed marriage record between a [John Woodson](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Woodson-102) b. 1655 in Curles, Henrico, Colony of Virginia and a [Mary Tucker](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Tucker-364) b. 1660 in Curles, Henrico, Colony of Virginia and married on 20 Aug 1681 in Curles, Henrico, Colony of Virginia.

The only sources for this marriage info provided on Wikitree are: *Title: Family Data Collection - Individual Records Author: Edmund West, comp. Publication: Online publication - Provo, UT, USA: Ancestry.com Operations Inc, 2000. Repository: Ancestry.com*.  There are two entries, one for John: *Birth year: 1655; Birth city: Curles; Birth state: Colony of Virginia. Data: Text: Birth date: 1655; Birth place: Curles, Henrico County, Colony of Virginia; Death date: 1 May 1700; Death place: Henrico County, Colony of Virginia; Marriage date: 20 August 1681 Marriage place: Henrico County, Colony of Virginia* and another for Mary: *Birth year: 1660; Birth city: Henrico Co; Birth state: Colony of Virginia. Data: Text: Birth date: 1660; Birth place: Henrico Co, Colony of Virginia; Death date: 1710; Death place: Curles, Henrico Co, Colony of Virginia; Marriage date: 20 August 1681; Marriage place: Henrico Co, Colony of Virginia*.

John may be a known Quaker of that same name, but if that is the case, he needs to have a son, John Woodson, Jr. See [U.S., Encyclopedia of American Quaker Genealogy, Vol I–VI, 1607-1943](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/3753/quakergenvolvi-005862?pid=322139); Note: See abbreviations on page 6.  Quote: WOODSON, continued ... [1699, 8, 6.  John Senior & John Junior served on a comm; first time names appeared](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/2189/42483_1821100519_4136-00011?pid=1101782703). ... [1699/1700, 12, 9.  John contributed 50 lbs tobacco toward the building of a MH at Curles.  1699/1700, 1, 8.  John, dec, it was ordered that the papers form in his hands but belonging to this MM be returned. ... 1700, 2, 12.  John & John Pleasants appointed to oversee the building of the new MH at Curles.](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/2189/42483_1821100519_4136-00011?pid=1101782703#?imageId=42483_1821100519_4136-00013) ... 1708/09, 1, 19.  John appointed overseer of the poor. ... 1714, 9, 12.  John, treasurer of this MM. ... 1760, 4, 5. Tucker & John, s Joseph, dis disorderly conduct.
Also see his possible son, John, discussed in 1716 MM.[U.S., Quaker Meeting Records, 1681-1935; Virginia Charles City Henrico Monthly Meeting The Record Book, 1699-1757](https://www.ancestry.com/interactive/2189/42483_1821100519_4136-00011?pid=1101782703#?imageId=42483_1821100519_4136-00086)

I do not locate their marriage in 1680-1808 — [Marriages of Henrico County, Virginia, 1680-1808](https://books.google.com/books?id=P53IPAAACAAJ) complied by Joyce H. Lindsay, Richmond, Virginia, 1960. [FHL Collection](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/112941).

Could it be because they were Quakers, their marriage is not registered with the County?

Comment: Please include the information you want to reference from WikiTree so people don't have to go digging for it on another site before they answer your question.  Your question could also be improved by putting more research effort into it, instead of attacking the problem like a 20th-century genealogy question.  Civil records on the county level don't start until 1706, according to the coverage table in the FamilySearch Research Wiki. https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Virginia_Vital_Records#Online_Birth.2C_Marriage_and_Death_Records_for_Virginia

Comment: Re: Ancestry's "Family Data Collection" records -- This may be of interest. http://www.tracingsbysam.com/gen%20tips/Not%20all%20Genealogy%20Databases%20are%20Created%20Equal.pdf

Comment: @JanMurphy I added the birth dates/locations, do you think any other information would be helpful to add besides birth?  The book I have starts in 1680, so where is it getting its data from pre-1706?

Comment: Please add the **source cited on the WikiTree profiles** for the marriage date and place. You could also add your sources for the John Woodson in that area known to be a Quaker.  Also, "where is [the book] getting its data?" is *exactly* the question you need to be asking about both the book and the information you're getting from WikiTree.

Comment: @JanMurphy Question updated as suggested.

Comment: You can't assume that the Sr/Jr of the same name are father/son or even related in this time period. See https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/5342/1006

Comment: @WilliamKF The book probably used religious records for the pre-1706 data.